# Jquery $.post() data is returning incorrectly

Tags: php, jquery

I run `$.post()` the first time witch returns the correct data json data to run the if statement but the next time `$.post()` is used it returns incorrectly causing the if statement to not work as intended.

My current Jquery code:

```
$.post('functions/write_settings.php', { dbname: $('#dbname').val(), dbhost: $('#dbhost').val(), dbpassword: $('#dbpassword').val(), dbusername: $('#dbusername').val(), dbprefix: $('#dbprefix').val() }, function(data){
    alert("here");
    try{var returndata = $.parseJSON(data);}catch(e){/*cont*/}
    alert("here1");
      if($(returndata).size() >= 1){
          for(var i = 0; i < $(returndata).size(); i++){
              $("#" + returndata[i]).css('background', 'url(style/install/database/imgs/textbox_error.png)');
          }
          ResetButton();
          alert("here2");
    }else{
        $.post('functions/check_settings.php', function(data){
            alert(data);
            var postdata = data;
            $.trim(postdata);
            if(postdata == 'error'){
                alert("test2");
                $('#pdbe').show();
                $('#pdbe').effect("pulsate", { times:10 }, 10000);
                ResetButton();
            }else if(data == '0'){
                alert('connected!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is check_settings.php

```
$cwd = getcwd();
$file = $cwd.'/dbconfig.php';
//check dbconfig created
if(file_exists($file)){
    include('./dbconfig.php');
}else{
    echo("error2");
    die();
}

//grab required vars
$host = $config['db']['host'];
$dbname = $config['db']['dbname'];

//test basic connection
try{
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
   echo("error");
   die();
}
echo("0");
```

Like i said the first `$.post()` returns the correct data while the second time when it uses it it will return incorrectly and cause the if statement to not work correctly.

any suggestions to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is returned the second time? What do you mean by "incorrectly"?

Comment: @JayBlanchard error is returned but when i alert it out it appears to have a large amount of white-space included in the response. But other then that the if statement is not working at all and i cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the error is the ability to connect to a database. it will return 0 if it can connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem the extra spaces? If so, in the check_settings.php you may be unknowingly printing spaces or new line. For example, you may be having space or new line before the first

Comment: Well there is no data to send, it just needs to call the script and get the returned information.

Comment: Specifying data is not required in the post() method. But perhaps the OP needs to specify the data for his purposes.

Comment: So is your problem the extra spaces? If so, in the check_settings.php you may be unknowingly printing spaces or new line. For example, you may be having space or new line before the first <?php...

Comment: @Vishnu This is what i originally thought but when you run the script on its own it simply outputs error or 0 with no spaces or extra data.

Comment: Check the exact data that you are getting from the server in firebug. I am pretty sure you will be getting those spaces in it. If so, for debugging, change echo("0") to die("0") and add ob_clean() before both error and 0. This will ensure that nothing is printed before or after error/0.